# Why do I get this error: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a dict like this:

```
{'d': {'BidVolume1': 0, 'BidPrice1': 0.0, 'BidVolume2': 0, 'BidPrice2': 0.0, 'BidVolume3': 0, 'BidPrice3': 0.0, 'BidVolume4': 0, 'BidPrice4': 0.0, 'BidVolume5': 0, 'BidPrice5': 0.0, 'AskTotalVolume': 0}}
```

When I try this code

```
for key in r['d'].items() :
    print(key['BidTotalVolume'])
```

I get the following error message:

> TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

What I am trying to do is to say to the program, give me the value of the item with the `BidTotalVolume` key.

How should I do that? Why do I get this error message?

Comment: try `for key,values in r['d'].items() :` and print `values`

Comment: you are asking for keys of your dictionary r like BidVolume1BidPrice1 etc. So key is a string and not a dict. what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there doesn't appear to be a bidtotalvolume key in your dictionary.

Secondly what you're attempting to do here is more or less:

```
print(r['d'][key]['BidTotalVolume'])
```

You don't have 3 levels to your dictionary so that's never going to work.

I assume what you mean to do is:

```
for key, value in r.items():
    print(r[key]['BidTotalVolume'])
```

Which will fail because BidTotalVolume is not in your dictionary.  But try it with any key that is in there and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

`r[d]` is `{'BidVolume1': 0, 'BidPrice1': 0.0, 'BidVolume2': 0, 'BidPrice2': 0.0, 'BidVolume3': 0, 'BidPrice3': 0.0, 'BidVolume4': 0, 'BidPrice4': 0.0, 'BidVolume5': 0, 'BidPrice5': 0.0, 'AskTotalVolume': 0}` so it's a dictionary.

Now you're iterating on a dictionary like this:

```
for key in r['d'].items()
```

the `key` name is misleading. Here `key` is a `tuple` of keys & values. When trying to use `[]` on that tuple you get that error. You should access your data directly like this:

```
print(r['d']['BidTotalVolume'])
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment, use
`for key, values in d.items():` as items () returns a tuple of (key, value). For only keys, you can use keys() and for only values , you can use values()